# How to extract item array from html

Tags: scrapy

I am using scrapy to extract an item list into an array with the following info:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p class="title">title info</p>
        <p class="content">txt info</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p class="title">title info</p>
        <p class="content">txt info</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Somehow my syntax seem to be wrong:

```
>>> response.xpath('//div[@class="row"]/div[@class="col-md-4"]/p/text()').extract()
[]
```

There might be another row class ahead of this item

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Does the `response.css('div.row div p::text').extract()` works? Because maybe you missed some spaces or other classes name in html. Can you send link to page?

Comment: it returns the content of another part. I am trying to extract the attributes from here: https://www.watchmaster.com/de/bvlgari/automatic/bb38sl-auto/UELG3X5E7R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to scrape https://www.watchmaster.com/de/bvlgari/automatic/bb38sl-auto/UELG3X5E7R page.

For example to collect Details from page it is better to add extra parent selector like here: `response.css("div#watch-details-tab div.row div ::text").extract()` to avoid collecting data from alike structures.

If you need to collect it by feature, try:

```
for row in response.css('div#watch-details-tab div.row div'):
    k = row.css('p.title::text').get()
    v = row.css('p.content::text').get()
    # and then your logic for this data
```

Comment: Something seems to be wrong, I am still not getting a result:
>>> fetch('https://www.watchmaster.com/de/bvlgari/automatic/bb38sl-auto/UELG3X5E7R')
2018-11-30 16:29:05 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.watchmaster.com/de/bvlgari/automatic/bb38sl-auto/UELG3X5E7R> (referer: None) ['cached']
>>> response.css("div#watch-details-tab div.row div ::text").extract()
[]

Comment: Check html of your response. I use scrapy shell and `response.css("div#watch-details-tab div.row div p::text").extract()` gives me `[u'Armband Material', u'Leder', u'Geh\xe4use',  u'Stahl', ......etc` Maybe they response with 200, but there is some blocking content for your IP?

Comment: You can show content of your response with pastebin, for example.

Comment: You are right, view(response) shows the page in my browser without those elements. Tried several VPNs and also different detailpages of their site. Same result. How did you get that scraped?

Comment: Well, I was with Switzerland VPN and everything worked fine for me with that selector. So, common `scrapy shell`, fetching url and then call `response.css...`. Try to use some certain proxy and scrape only with it. At least you will get one variant of layout. Hope so :)

Comment: Do you identify as srapy? An apache log would look like this from my crawl: ""GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 9890 "-" "Scrapy/1.5.1 (+https://scrapy.org)"". The browser renders the page OK. Maybe they block for the identifier? Also if I use fetch, I always get the "cashed" version, despite the non cache setting.

Comment: Got i! Changed to another user agent and cleaned the cash. Thank you for your help.